# Elisp equivalent of Clojure's time?

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp

Here's Clojure's doc:

```
clojure.core/time
([expr])
Macro
  Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
 expr.
```

Is there some (semi-) standard way to do this in Emacs lisp?

Comment: Thanks, @giordano. That's precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try [Emacs Lisp Benchmark](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispBenchmark)